# Git won't delete a file and always thinks the working directory is dirty

Tags: git

I was trying to put a new Rails app on Heroku, and had deleted the default index file public/index.html.  However, to my surprise, when I visited my app on Heroku, I was shown the default index page instead of what index that I wanted to see.

OK, that's a little strange, but I guess there could be some reason like Git not removing the file from the repository even though I deleted it.  So I looked up on the internet how to force Git to remove files from the repository and came up with

`git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm public/index.html' HEAD`

When I ran this, however, it said "Cannot rewrite branch(es) with dirty working directory".  I was unsure why my working directory was dirty, since I had just committed, and when I ran `git status` it said

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    public/index.html
```

This was confusing to me because I had deleted public/index.html quite a while ago.  Why should it be the only change left?  Still, I ran `git add .` and `git commit -m "..."` and it said

```
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    public/index.html
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I then, irritated, tried `git add .` and `git status` and saw that the change was simply not being added.  `git add public/index.html` and `git rm public/index.html` didn't do anything for me either.  Then I googled the problem, and came up with a StackOverflow post where someone suggested trying `git stash` and `git stash apply` to refresh.  I did that, and things still weren't working.

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to "add" the deleted file and then commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to commit the delete basically, so do a git commit -a -m '[comment]' and then it'll accept your delete

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the git filter-branch, it would remove the file from all the commits in the repo, if that is what you intended. Just make commit or stash your changes before doing it. If you just want it deleted from now on than seansmash's answer is probably what you need.